# Varnish not caching because of language cookie, how to correct behaviour?

Tags: varnish, cookie

I am using Varnish 4 + Pagespeed on Nginx successfully, but varnish is not hitting the cache because the site always pushes a language cookie, disregarding if user is authenticated or not.

That makes sense because during the visit, the user may change the language on the site and the cookie provides the info about about what language is being used.

So, how can I make Varnish cache pages for both languages instead of just avoiding caching and subsequently hitting back ?

The full config here :

```
# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

import std;

# Block 1: Define upstream server's host and port. Set this to point to your
# content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

# Block 2: Define a key based on the User-Agent which can be used for hashing.
# Also set the PS-CapabilityList header for PageSpeed server to respect.
sub generate_user_agent_based_key {
    # Define placeholder PS-CapabilityList header values for large and small
    # screens with no UA dependent optimizations. Note that these placeholder
    # values should not contain any of ll, ii, dj, jw or ws, since these
    # codes will end up representing optimizations to be supported for the
    # request.
    set req.http.default_ps_capability_list_for_large_screens = "LargeScreen.SkipUADependentOptimizations:";
    set req.http.default_ps_capability_list_for_small_screens = "TinyScreen.SkipUADependentOptimizations:";

    # As a fallback, the PS-CapabilityList header that is sent to the upstream
    # PageSpeed server should be for a large screen device with no browser
    # specific optimizations.
    set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = req.http.default_ps_capability_list_for_large_screens;

    # Cache-fragment 1: Desktop User-Agents that support lazyload_images (ll),
    # inline_images (ii) and defer_javascript (dj).
    # Note: Wget is added for testing purposes only.
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)Chrome/|Firefox/|MSIE |Safari|Wget") {
      set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = "ll,ii,dj:";
    }
    # Cache-fragment 2: Desktop User-Agents that support lazyload_images (ll),
    # inline_images (ii), defer_javascript (dj), webp (jw) and lossless_webp
    # (ws).
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~
        "(?i)Chrome/[2][3-9]+\.|Chrome/[[3-9][0-9]+\.|Chrome/[0-9]{3,}\.") {
      set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = "ll,ii,dj,jw,ws:";
    }
    # Cache-fragment 3: This fragment contains (a) Desktop User-Agents that
    # match fragments 1 or 2 but should not because they represent older
    # versions of certain browsers or bots and (b) Tablet User-Agents that
    # on all browsers and use image compression qualities applicable to large
    # screens. Note that even tablets that are capable of supporting inline or
    # webp images, e.g. Android 4.1.2, will not get these advanced
    # optimizations.
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)Firefox/[1-2]\.|MSIE [5-8]\.|bot|Yahoo!|Ruby|RPT-HTTPClient|(Google \(\+https\:\/\/developers\.google\.com\/\+\/web\/snippet\/\))|Android|iPad|TouchPad|Silk-Accelerated|Kindle Fire") {
      set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = req.http.default_ps_capability_list_for_large_screens;
    }
    # Cache-fragment 4: Mobiles and small screen tablets will use image
    # compression qualities applicable to small screens, but all other
    # optimizations will be those that work on all browsers.
    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)Mozilla.*Android.*Mobile*|iPhone|BlackBerry|Opera Mobi|Opera Mini|SymbianOS|UP.Browser|J-PHONE|Profile/MIDP|portalmmm|DoCoMo|Obigo|Galaxy Nexus|GT-I9300|GT-N7100|HTC One|Nexus [4|7|S]|Xoom|XT907") {
      set req.http.PS-CapabilityList = req.http.default_ps_capability_list_for_small_screens;
    }
    # Remove placeholder header values.
    unset req.http.default_ps_capability_list_for_large_screens;
    unset req.http.default_ps_capability_list_for_large_screens;
}

sub vcl_hash {
  # Block 3: Use the PS-CapabilityList value for computing the hash.
  hash_data(req.http.PS-CapabilityList);
}

# Block 3a: Define ACL for purge requests
acl purge {
  # Purge requests are only allowed from localhost.
  "localhost";
  "127.0.0.1";
}


# Block 4: In vcl_recv, on receiving a request, call the method responsible for
# generating the User-Agent based key for hashing into the cache.
sub vcl_recv {
  # We want to support beaconing filters, i.e., one or more of inline_images,
  # lazyload_images, inline_preview_images or prioritize_critical_css are
  # enabled. We define a placeholder constant called ps_should_beacon_key_value
  # so that some percentages of hits and misses can be sent to the backend
  # with this value used for the PS-ShouldBeacon header to force beaconing.
  # This value should match the value of the DownstreamCacheRebeaconingKey
  # pagespeed directive used by your backend server.
  # WARNING: Do not use "random_rebeaconing_key" for your configuration, but
  # instead change it to something specific to your site, to keep it secure.
  set req.http.ps_should_beacon_key_value = "random_rebeaconing_key";

  # Incoming PS-ShouldBeacon headers should not be allowed since this will allow
  # external entities to force the server to instrument pages.
  unset req.http.PS-ShouldBeacon;

  call generate_user_agent_based_key;
  # Block 3d: Verify the ACL for an incoming purge request and handle it.
  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
      return (synth(405,"Not allowed."));
    }
    return (purge);
  }
  # Blocks which decide whether cache should be bypassed or not go here.

  # Block 5a: Bypass the cache for .pagespeed. resource. PageSpeed has its own
  # cache for these, and these could bloat up the caching layer.
  if (req.url ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+") {
    # Skip the cache for .pagespeed. resource.  PageSpeed has its own
    # cache for these, and these could bloat up the caching layer.
    return (pass);
  }

  # Block 5b: Only cache responses to clients that support gzip.  Most clients
  # do, and the cache holds much more if it stores gzipped responses.
  if (req.http.Accept-Encoding !~ "gzip") {
    return (pass);
  }
  # --- Wordpress specific configuration

  # Did not cache the RSS feed
  if (req.url ~ "/feed") {
    return (pass);
  }
  # Blitz hack
  if (req.url ~ "/mu-.*") {
  return (pass);
  }
  # Did not cache the admin and login pages
  if (req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin)") {
  return (pass);
  }
  # Remove the "has_js" cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  # Remove the wp test cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
            unset req.http.cookie;
  }
  # Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
  if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
  return (pass);
  }
  if (!req.http.cookie) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
  }
  #Avoid caching Woocommerce areas
  if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account|checkout|addons)") {
  return (pass);
  }
  if ( req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
  return (pass);
  }

}


# Block 6: Mark HTML uncacheable by caches beyond our control.
sub vcl_backend_response {
   if (beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html") {
     # Hide the upstream cache control header.
     unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
     # Add no-cache Cache-Control header for html.
     set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache, max-age=0";
   }
}


sub vcl_hit { 
  if (std.random(0, 100) < 5) {
    set req.http.PS-ShouldBeacon = req.http.ps_should_beacon_key_value;
    return (pass);
  }
}

sub vcl_miss {
  # Send 25% of the MISSes to the backend for instrumentation.
  if (std.random(0, 100) < 25) {
    set req.http.PS-ShouldBeacon = req.http.ps_should_beacon_key_value;
    return (pass);
  }
}

# Block 7: Add a header for identifying cache hits/misses.
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the cookie to the hash, so everyone with those cookies receives their own version of the cached site content.

Documentation here:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html

Override the default VCL, so having that cookie doesn't automatically mean you don't get cached.